# What does морду тебе за это самое набью mean?

Tags: грамматика

Смотри, Востяков, как в тело войду, морду тебе за это самое набью окончательно.

I'm confused from морду onwards, the cases are throwing me off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ВХОДИТЬ В ТЕЛО. ВОЙТИ В ТЕЛО. Прост. Экспрес. Физически крепнуть; поправляться, полнеть.to get stronger.

морду тебе за это самое набью окончательно= **(Я) набью тебе ( dative) морду (accusative) за это (accusative) окончательно**.= I (which is omitted) will beat your face (you in the face) for this (which should be known from the previous context) surely (by all means).

**When I get stronger I will surely beat you in the face for this/that**.

Comment: Here the (old) colloquial use of "окончательно" (liter. "finally" as in "with finality") would be better translated as "thoroughly".